# Extract a string from Response Body in Jmeter

Tags: parsing, testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing

I am trying to set up an automated test in jmeter. However I am having a problem extracting a string from an array of numbers that are returned from an api call.

Currently Im recieving [1069936,1069931,1038673,1059014,1061326,1074842,1076998,1069605,1060567,1063853,2021064,2024239,1074835,1075227,1076997,1078435] but i would like to extract "1069936" and use it in the next api call. Ive tried -1 in the Match No. column of the Json Extractor but cant find any documentation to help.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON Extractor Post Processor as a child of Sampler Returning JSON Response.

Note : -1 will capture every matching possible. So use -1 when you want all the matches for that particular expression. Here you need the first match and not all matches.

[image]

[image]